# Matlab graph disappearing when adding linespec

Tags: matlab, plot, simulation

so I have this planet simulation in which I'd like to plot the position of the planets (so an unbroken line that follows the planets as they move around) and have tried using so many different variations of linespec. I believe the problem might be because I use a "set(h..)" function first and then plot within a loop but I'm not sure.

```
clc, close all, clear all

%% Constants
m_sun=1.9891*10^(30); % Sun mass KG
m_earth=5.972*10^(24); 
G=1.4879*10^(-34); %Gravitational constant %AU^3/(kg*day^2) %Because JPL Data..
n=36500; %1 year is 36.5 because 1 step is 10 days so this is 10 years.
dt=1; %Stepsize is by the DATA from JPL aut. set to 10 days (dt=1 aka 10 days)

%% Start pos. and velocity for Sun, Mercury, Venus, Earth and Moon
psol=[0 0 0];

%% Mercury
x_mercury=-1.433719457930228E-01; %AU
y_mercury=2.837093715285307E-01; %AU
z_mercury=3.633570612044031E-02; %AU

vx_mercury=-3.076848842366683E-02; %AU/Day
vy_mercury=-1.162353364156454E-02; %AU/Day
vz_mercury=1.872970822663991E-03;

v0_mercury=[vx_mercury vy_mercury vz_mercury];
p0_mercury=[x_mercury y_mercury z_mercury];
v_mercury=v0_mercury;
p_mercury=p0_mercury;

%% Venus
x_venus=4.673243997906552E-01; %AU
y_venus=5.508231287051383E-01; %AU
z_venus=-1.941467305848078E-02; %AU

vx_venus=-1.548526759260772E-02; %AU/Day
vy_venus=1.299852601837024E-02; %AU/Day
vz_venus=1.071832461568199E-03; %AU/Day

v0_venus=[vx_venus vy_venus vz_venus];
p0_venus=[x_venus y_venus z_venus];
v_venus=v0_venus;
p_venus=p0_venus;

%% Earth
x_jord=-1.796136519182077E-01; %AU
y_jord=9.667949205028737E-01; %AU
z_jord=-3.668730384613077E-05; %AU

vx_jord=-1.720038360546182E-02; %AU/Day
vy_jord=-3.211186215649903E-03; %AU/Day
vz_jord=7.927770738232715E-07; %AU/Day

v0_jord=[vx_jord vy_jord vz_jord];
p0_jord=[x_jord y_jord z_jord];
v_jord=v0_jord;
p_jord=p0_jord;

%% Moon 
x_moon=1.735515971173234E-03; %AU
y_moon=-1.954900859093033E-03; %AU
z_moon=9.023023109649464E-05; %AU

vx_moon=4.195999130374965E-04; %AU/Day
vy_moon=4.002519066694706E-04; %AU/Day
vz_moon=-4.849066257645466E-05; %AU/Day

v0_moon=[vx_moon vy_moon vz_moon];
p0_moon=[x_moon y_moon z_moon];
v_moon=v0_moon;
p_moon=p0_moon;


%% Calculations
hold on
h_sun = plot3(0,0,0,'y.','markersize',80);
h_mercury = plot3(1,1,1,'k.','markersize',35);
h_venus = plot3(2,2,2,'m.','markersize',45);
h_earth = plot3(3,3,3,'b.','markersize',55);
h_moon = plot3(4,4,4,'r.','markersize',25);

for step=1:n
      %% Mercury
      r_vekt_mercury=-p_mercury;
      r_mercury=sqrt(x_mercury^2 + y_mercury^2 + z_mercury^2); %Radius in AU
      a_mercury=((G*m_sun)/((r_mercury)^3))*r_vekt_mercury;
      v_mercury=a_mercury*dt+v_mercury;
      p_mercury=v_mercury*dt+p_mercury;

      %% Venus
      r_vekt_venus=-p_venus;
      r_venus=sqrt(x_venus^2 + y_venus^2 + z_venus^2); %Radius in AU
      a_venus=((G*m_sun)/((r_venus)^3))*r_vekt_venus;
      v_venus=a_venus*dt+v_venus;
      p_venus=v_venus*dt+p_venus;

      %% Jord
      r_vekt_jord=-p_jord;
      r_jord=sqrt(x_jord^2 + y_jord^2 + z_jord); %Radius in AU
      a_jord=((G*m_sun)/((r_jord)^3))*r_vekt_jord;
      v_jord=a_jord*dt+v_jord;
      p_jord=v_jord*dt+p_jord;

%     %% Moon
      %r_vekt_moon=psol-p_moon;
      r_vekt_moon_earth=p_jord-p_moon;
      r_moon=sqrt(x_moon^2 + y_moon^2 + z_moon^2); %Radius in AU
      a_moon=((G*m_earth)/((r_moon)^3))*r_vekt_moon_earth;
      v_moon=a_moon*dt+v_moon;
      p_moon=v_moon*dt+p_moon;

      set(h_sun,'XData',psol(1),'YData',psol(2),'ZData',psol(3));    
      set(h_mercury,'XData',p_mercury(1),'YData',p_mercury(2),'ZData',p_mercury(3));
      set(h_venus,'XData',p_venus(1),'YData',p_venus(2),'ZData',p_venus(3));
      set(h_earth,'XData',p_jord(1),'YData',p_jord(2),'ZData',p_jord(3));
      set(h_moon,'XData',p_moon(1),'YData',p_moon(2),'ZData',p_moon(3));
      xlabel('AU');
      ylabel('AU');
      zlabel('AU');
      axis([-2 2 -2 2 -2 2]);
      drawnow;
      hold off
  end
```

So if you look before the loop you'll see the "set(...)" function i mentioned and in the end of the loop is the plotting. If I change i.e. @ h_mercury from 'k.' to 'k' the planet disappears completely. If I change it to '-.' it disappears as well. I've tried countless variations and either the planet disappears or it gives me an error. I've looked at the help section @matlabs website within 2d plot, 3d plot, linespec etc and still haven't found a solution!

I hope someone can help me figure this out as quick as possible!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your plots for each planet are line plots with a single point (`plot3(0,0,0,'k.',...)`). This means that when you specify a marker, your single point will be equipped with a marker and that is how you see it. Currently, you are using the dot marker ('k.'). If you remove the dot, there is no more marker and also no line since there are no two points to connect.

Your `set(...)` updates the plot not by adding points to it but by moving the single point you plotted originally. To see what happens, type `inspect(h_mercury)`, you will notice that its `XData`, `YData`, `ZData` contains only a single point.

If you want to draw lines with the previous points, you need to add them to the plot. There are at least two ways:

- Add a `plot3(p_mercury(1),p_mercury(2),p_mercury(3),'k.'))` to your loop. This will put additional plot points at all the positions that were already visited. Though this is simple it's not necessarily the best: there will not be a solid line connecting the dots and if you make a lot of steps this will add a lot of points and hence make the animation slow. If you want to use this, you also have to delete the `hold off` command at the end of the loop since otherwise the `plot3` clears the plot.
- Better: Memorize the trajectory in an array and have two plots, one for the current position (dot marker), one for the trajectory (line). Something like this:

.

```
h_mercury = plot3(1,1,1,'k.','markersize',35);
h_mercury_trajectory = plot3(1,1,1,'k-');

p_mercury_trajectory = zeros(3,n);
for step = 1:n
    % your calculation of positions...
    p_mercury = ...
    p_mercury_trajectory(:,step) = p_mercury;

    % rest of the loop ...

    % update plots
    set(h_mercury,'XData',p_mercury(1),'YData',p_mercury(2),'ZData',p_mercury(3));
    set(h_mercury_trajectory,'XData',p_mercury_trajectory(1,1:step),'YData',p_mercury_trajectory(2,1:step),'ZData',p_mercury_trajectory(3,1:step));
end
```

Here is what it looks like shortly after the beginning:

[image: Screenshot of orbit simulation]

Is that what you had in mind?

**one more edit**: Since I really liked your animation, I converted sun and planets into spheres with light coming from the center (sun). I kind of like the effect. This is what it looks like:

[image: Screenshot of modified orbit simulation]

The orbit of moon is a bit exaggerated though, right?

Anyways, the modified script is here: https://nopaste.me/view/473add8f

Comment: So I tried the code you wrote but it only added a line from the sun to the planet (I only tried with Mercury to see how it would look) that follower the planet around something like a bridge from the planet to the sun. What is the reason for this?

And as for the other solution you wrote would I then add the plot3(...) after the set(...) aka just before the end of the loop?

Comment: I had made a small mistake. My apologies. I edited my solution and tested it here, it should work now.

Comment: Exactly! I will try to copy what you've created and add it to all my planets! If you want to explain a bit further I'd love to actually try to understand what your code does and not just copy it!

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure how I can explain it better. It's basically two plots per planet: one line plot that plots the whole trajectory from the start to the current step, i.e., lines between `step` points in 3-D. In addition one plot that only plots a single marker at the current position of the planet, which is a large filled dot. The `set` commands update both, the marker plot (`h_mercury`) and the trajectory plot (`h_mercury`) with the current point (`p_mercury`) and its trajectory (`p_mercury_trajectory(:,1:step)`), respectively. Please ask further if anything is still unclear.

Comment: I modified the animation a bit more since I really liked it. Now includes lightning, see my last edit.

Comment: Yeah it looks great! And yes the moons orbit is kinda weird.. I couldn't figure out how to create a correct amount of gravity for the moon although I know that the gravity the sun pulls on the moon is a factor 2.2 large than what the earth pulls on the moon. Thanks for all the help and the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

**Line Formatting**

You sat the line is disappearing when you change the style from `'k.'` to `'k'`, you are plotting a single point (formatted as a dot from `.`) so if you don't plot the dot marker, you have no visible line! See below for code which can be used to plot a continuous trace or moving dots.

**Suggested Code**

I've omitted the `Set` commands entirely and simply re-plotted each iteration, see below...

```
% Previous code omitted
% < ... >

%% Calculations

for step=1:n

    % < ... >
    % Code omitted for clarity, do calculations for each planet as in question
    % < ... >

    % Replace use of SET with continued use of PLOT3

    % Clear figure from previous plot and hold on
    figure(1)
    clf          % << Remove if you don't want the previous points to disappear
    hold on

    % Do all plotting
    h_sun = plot3(psol(1),psol(2),psol(3),'y.','markersize',80);
    h_mercury = plot3(p_mercury(1),p_mercury(2),p_mercury(3),'k.','markersize',35);
    h_venus = plot3(p_venus(1),p_venus(2),p_venus(3),'m.','markersize',45);
    h_earth = plot3(p_jord(1),p_jord(2),p_jord(3),'b.','markersize',55);
    h_moon = plot3(p_moon(1),p_moon(2),p_moon(3),'r.','markersize',25);

    % Format, hold off, draw
    xlabel('AU');
    ylabel('AU');
    zlabel('AU');       
    axis([-2 2 -2 2 -2 2]);     
    hold off        
    drawnow;

end
```

Comment: So I moved the PLOT3 which was outside my loop to inside my loop right after my calcs. and replaced the SET with PLOT3. This did fix the problem but it just adds the (previous) points and as such the marker instead of adding a line behind the moving marker.

Comment: Couldn't edit my comment but I just noticed that it also turned my 3d simulation into a 2d simulation

Comment: So you have: plotting which updates as per simulation. You want: the same but with a line of previously calculated values too? Also this doesn't change your simulation at all so I'm not sure what you mean by saying it's now 2D?